# Is it possible to detect file or folder creation/deletion in real time?

Tags: linux, files, filesystems, directory, mkdir

I want to monitor file or folder creation/deletion instantaneously, is it possible?

EDIT:I am  using Ubuntu 16.04

Comment: In a specific directory, or across the whole server, or...?

Comment: Have you check `man auditd`?

Comment: @StephenHarris I ll accept whichever one is possible

Comment: @RomeoNinov `No manual entry for auditd`

Comment: https://linux.die.net/man/8/auditd and http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/xenial/man8/auditd.8.html provide you man pages.

Answer (score 6):

That's possible in linux using the `inotify(7)` interface.

A simple sample command line tool using that is `inotifywait(1)`. Example:

```
inotifywait -mr /tmp
```

will print all kind of events (files opened, created) that happen inside the `/tmp` directory. The `-r` option tells it to set watches recursively on subdirectories, and the `-m` option not to exit after the first event.

The set of events watched can be restricted with the `-e` option: eg. `-e create,delete` to only print info about directory entries that were created or deleted.

Comment: I knew this tool indeed, but I read that it's not efficient in huge filesystem trees.

Comment: nothing is efficient in huge filesystem trees; and watching all processes in real time is even worse.

Comment: `sudo apt install inotify-tools` to install it on Ubuntu

Answer (score 4):

The simplest (for me) way is to use the [auditd](https://github.com/linux-audit/audit-userspace) daemon ([man page](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/xenial/man8/auditd.8.html)) after installation. You can monitor file operations in `/var/run` directory by starting the daemon and adding this directory to be audited:

```
auditctl -w /var/run/ -p rw -k var-run-pids
```

With this command you can check the log of daemon where most of info is written:

```
tail -20 /var/log/audit/audit.log
```

With this command you can search in audit log for particular events:

```
ausearch -f /var/run
```

You can send messages thusly (from the [man page of auditctl](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man8/auditctl.8.html)):

> `-m text`
>
>   Send a user space message into the audit system. 
>     This can only be done if you have
>   `CAP_AUDIT_WRITE`
>   capability
>     (normally the root user
>     has this).  The resulting event will be the USER type.

Comment: This seems what I want. Is it also possible to get modified file alerts with this tool ?

Comment: @kenn, if some other software can generate alarm - yes. But I do not think this software itself can do this. This software is for audit: who, when, what did.

Comment: @kenn, you can do it, audit daemon can send messages in userspace (but only to root) `-m text`